# Run Firebase NextJS app function on root url

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, next.js

I'm trying to run my NextJS app deployed via Firebase on the root url but it only seems to run on `/next`, this comes with some issues for my assets' paths and I just want it to run on the root url. If I go to the root url now I get this error:

[image]

---

How do I get it to run on the root url `https://europe-west2-myfirstflutterapp-xxxxx.cloudfunctions.net/` instead of `https://europe-west2-myfirstflutterapp-xxxxx.cloudfunctions.net/next`?

My `firebase.json`:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "./public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "next"
      }
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "source": "functions"
  }
}
```

My `functions/index.js`:

```js
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const next = require('next');
const path = require('path');

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
// const app = next({dev, dir: path.join(__dirname, '../'), conf: {distDir: 'next'}});
const app = next({dev, conf: {distDir: 'next'}});
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

exports.next = functions.region('europe-west2').https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  console.log('File: ' + req.originalUrl); // log the page.js file that is being requested
  await app.prepare();
  handle(req, res);
});
```

Comment: Could you edit the question to show in more detail the actual URL paths you're trying, and how the function isn't working the way you expect with them?

Comment: @DougStevenson done!

Comment: You've changed the default `.next` dist dir to `next`. Are you running a built version of nextjs (`next build`) or a live development server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Functions doesn't let you trigger functions off the root of the hostname allocated for you automatically under "cloudfunctions.net".

If you meant to use Firebase Hosting as a proxy to Cloud Functions, you will have to use your Firebase Hosting domain name instead.  That will be either "your-project.firebaseapp.com" or "your-project.web.app" by default.  That will use the rewrite rules in your firebase.json.

Comment: What do you mean by "redirect"?  In formal web terms, that means your browser got sent to a different URL than the first one.  Is that really what happened?  Did the Cloud Function execute? Was anything left in the functions log?

Comment: I messed around with the GCP resource location and looks like that was the issue, it's working now. Thanks for helping me out!